# Can I use my motherboard's HDMI port along with Graphic Card HDMI port?

Tags: multiple-monitors, cpu, motherboard, hdmi, gpu

I have purchased a Ryzen 5 2600 CPU and Asus Prime A320M-K motherboard. I wss informed by my seller that I would compulsarily need Graphic Card with this CPU, so I purchased MSI Geforce GTX 1650 Ventus XS edition. I was planning to purchase a secondary monitor, however my seller informed me that I can only use the ports on my GPU (which only had 1 HDMI port which is already exausted by my primary monitor).

Is that true that I cannot use the HDMI or VGA ports on my motherboard and can only use the ports on my GPU in this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to use the ports on your GPU. Your card has a display port and a DVI port as well. So if you get a second monitor, get one that has one of those ports. If you happen to get one that doesn't you can buy a cable that is display port to HDMI, or whatever combination you may end up with.

Comment: Thanks very much @DrZoo